# Is it necessary to enable Vertical or Horizontal Pod Autoscaling in GKE Autopilot Clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

For a GKE cluster configured with Autopilot, does it make sense to also enable autoscaling?

In the document [Compare GKE Autopilot and Standard](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/resources/autopilot-standard-feature-comparison), it says the auto scaler are optional.

Also [node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#overview) says:

> With Autopilot clusters, you don't need to manually provision nodes or manage node pools because node pools are automatically provisioned through node auto-provisioning. With node auto-provisioning, nodes are automatically scaled to meet the requirements of your workloads.

EDIT: I am confused between the concepts of autoscaling and auto node provisioning.

Comment: Autoscaling and vertical pod autoscaling are both enabled on Autopilot clusters.  The "optional" part of Autopilot is deploying HPA and VPA resources themselves.  The controllers are already pre-deployed/configured.

Comment: So my deployment must tell GKE how the workload can be auto-scaled. Just because nodes are auto provisioned doesn't mean they will scale up unless the deployment tells them how.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to enable Vertical or Horizontal Pod Autoscaling in
> GKE Autopilot Clusters?

Not necessary, but if using autopilot it's about leveraging the option to scale **nodes** without worry and just you focus on HPA & VPA.

> For a GKE cluster is configured with Autopilot, does it make sense to
> also enable autoscaling?

I think would be **beneficial** to you to enable Autoscaling like **HPA & VPA** with **GKE autopilot** mode if using. You can also go with HPA and Max POD limit to scale.

**VPA** would be also good to create small-size **POD** when there is less traffic or resource consumption there, which will be a good factor in **reducing** **cost** also.

> In the document Compare GKE Autopilot and Standard, it says the
> autoscalers are optional.

Yes, it's optional but would be good to go initially with **HPA** scaling so if there is any sudden traffic spike will be able to handle it.

> Also node auto-provisioning says:

Yes with Autopilot cluster you don't have to worry about the Ifra part like Node pool setup, size, Node pool's scaling etc. With **autopilot**, you just worry about your application and its scaling with **HPA & VPA**.

**HPA** scales the replicas of **POD** as per your setting while if required **Node** **auto-scaled** by Google and get attached to your GKE cluster without setting up **cluster(node) autoscaler** by you.

While with **GKE standard** you have to worry about the size of **Node pool** scaling etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I guess my question should really be about how do these features work together - which is a more complex discussion.

Comment: you can post the new question for more details feel free to update the status of question. you can also do upvote if found answer helpful or mark as accepted if resolve your issues.